# Why don't the Assassin's Creed novels include present day events?

Tags: setting, assassins-creed

The *Assassin's Creed* games mostly have a present-day component, where the protagonist's descendent enters the Animus, reliving the protagonist's life. Since this is merely replaying memories, we don't actually affect the past in the game, but, in *Assassin's Creed II: Revelations*:

> With the power of the Piece of Eden, Ezio the ancestor communicates with Desmond the descendent.

However, from the AC novels I have read (the first five to be published, IIRC), there is no mention at all of present day events. I don't recall how exactly the event in the spoiler block happened in the corresponding book, but Desmond Miles makes no appearance, of that I am sure.

Why aren't the present day events and characters part of the AC books?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55399/discussion-on-question-by-muru-why-dont-the-assassins-creed-novels-include-pre).

Comment: Or better yet, [you can express your thoughts on the downvotability of this question on meta](http://meta.literature.stackexchange.com/q/607/111).